# Pass many values to eval function

Tags: r, data.table

I am using eval to simplify my R code:

```
Income = quote(ifelse(Cash > 0, Cash, 0))

MonthlyIncome = data[, sum(eval(Income)), by = month(Date)]
```

Now I am looking for solution to pass more than one column to data.table using eval function, but something like:

```
x  = quote(column1, column2)
```

is of course not allowed. Any workaround to use evaluation for many columns?

Comment: "I am using eval to simplify my R code" say what now?

Comment: look into `expression`, which i believe is what you want.

Comment: @HongOoi Business logic. I can define it once (like Income) and use later in calculations. Is it better approach?

Comment: Why not using **dplyr** for this?

Comment: @F.Privé Code is written in data.table.

Comment: I think you want the classic lapply(.SD, ...) in combination with .SDcols. And of course I'd try to avoid (the inefficient) ifelse.

Comment: @F.Privé **Why on earth using dplyr for this**?

Comment: @Kulis there is absolutely no need in `quote` or `eval` here (I'm not sure where did you get that idea from). You should just do `f <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, x, 0) ; data[, lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = c("column1", "column2"), by = month(Date)]` (expending Rolands comment)

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is just a `group_by` and a `summarize`, right?

Comment: @F.Privé So? Why can't they use data.table for this? Why use dplyr which literally incapable of doing a simple standard evaluation without introducing a bunch of packages and tons of convoluted code (rlang and lazyeval)?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The syntax of **dplyr** is often easier than the one of **data.table** so if you don't care about performance, I think it is always a good idea to use **dplyr**. Never mind.

Comment: @F.Privé "easier" is subjective. I think that data.tables syntax is much much better and more concise. Not to mention that dplyr is very unstable, it masks tons of base R functions such as `lag`, it adds tons of dependencies (data.table doesn't have a single dependency) which can be in turn unstable, it's functions keep changing their functionality or getting constantly deprecated, it can't handle SE without really messing your code,  and I can go on for hours. So, no, I won't use dplyr at any circumstances, regardless of its performance.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your solution is faster, more elegant, the only possible or what? I just want to understand the right approach.

Comment: In general, there is no reason to quote or evaluate anything in R unless you really have to. This is a functional language and you are just supposed to use it's functions as is. Unless you are expecting some unknown input or such- in that case you will usually go for the `eval` approach. In either-way, the idiomatic data.table approach is what I've showed, while you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Anyway, is it better to put this kind of filters (ifelse(Cash > 0, Cash, 0)) in i or j part of data.table, for one aggregation (sum)?